# Parse Timezone using curl

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

My example timezone website is like [this](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/canada/toronto), how am I able to get its current timezone by using `curl` in bash terminal console?

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -sS https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/canada/toronto | grep -o '"/time/zones/[a-z]\+[^>]*>[^<]*' | head -n1 | grep -o '[^>]*$'
```

output: `EST`

If you need another value from the website please adjust the regex to your needs.

*Edit: `-sS`*

Comment: Thanks Samuel Kirschner. After I executed the above command line, I got this:\n % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 29472    0 29472    0     0   2853      0 --:--:--  0:00:10 --:--:--  2853

Comment: just ignore the stderr, or pipe it to `/dev/null` or use `curl -sS`

Comment: What specific Linux are you on? I can't get what you had `EST`. Thanks again, Samuel Kirschner.